# change appearance of multiline checkboxes with ipyvuetify

Tags: python, ipywidgets, ipyvuetify

I would like to create a multiline checkbox with ipyvuetify:

```
v.Col(children=[vue.Checkbox(label='UNO'),vue.Checkbox(label='DOS'),vue.Checkbox(label='TRES'),vue.Checkbox(label='CUATRO')])
```

The result is as follows:

[image]

How do I modify the component in order to get the checkboxes lines closer to each other?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do this by specifying the margin and padding via [vuetifys CSS spacing classes](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/spacing/).
Here I used negativ margin to bring them even closer together. It's all explained in the link:

```
vue.Col(
    children = [
        vue.Checkbox(
            class_='ma-n3',
            label='UNO'
        ),
        vue.Checkbox(
            class_='ma-n3',
            label='DOS'
        ),
        vue.Checkbox(
            class_='ma-n3',
            label='TRES'
        ),
        vue.Checkbox(
            class_='ma-n3',
            label='CUATRO'
        )
    ]
)
```